# Hyperlink between two Excel worksheets

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I am working with two separate Excel sheets:

```
SHEET1 
Apple    TEST1
Banana   TEST2
Orange   TEST3

SHEET2
Orange
Apple
Banana
```

What I'm trying to do is to create an hyperlink connecting TEST1 (SHEET1) and Apple(SHEET2).
So when I click on TEST1, the hyperlink should open SHEET2 on the cell Apple.
I do not want to make it manually because I have a lot (1000+) of observations not in the same order in the two sheets.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can enter this formula in `cell B1` and drag down.

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,0),1),"TEST"&ROW())
```

The key is to use `#` sign to point to a different sheet.